# How to filter the total sales record every month using sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am generating a sales report and I am having a hard time with the query. I am not really good in query. I hope you can help me with this. Ok here it is.

I have a sales table. And the structure is like this
EX:

```
product_id       name             date_purchased
1                apple          2014-01-03 12:00:59
2                orange         2014-01-05 10:12:20
3                banana         2014-02-01 09:25:01
4                mango          2014-02-20 18:13:25
5                stawberry      2014-02-28 13:14:30
6                jackfruit      2014-05-26 08:16:31
7                grapes         2014-11-03 09:25:21
8                guava          2014-12-25 10:15:45
```

Now I want to count the item purchased every month
My output result should be like this

2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1

2 represents Jan,
3 represents Feb,
etc...

My query looks like this but I know it is wrong.. :(

```
SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM sales_table GROUP BY date_purchased
```

How can I do that using a query? Or should I make a PHP function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this :

```
SELECT year(date_purchased), month(date_purchased), COUNT(product_id) 
FROM sales_table 
GROUP BY concat(year(date_purchased), month(date_purchased))
```

Comment: The result of the query you have is this: 2014, 8, 24

Comment: @Jerielle : on the same data than in your example ?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query is enough.
You have to use group by.
But first make a month column for your table.

```
create function byMonth(@myDate datetime)
    returns datetime
as
    begin
    declare @newDate
    set @newDate = year(@myDate) + '/' + month(@myDate) + '/1 00:00:00'
    return @newDate
    end
go
```

and use this in your query:

```
Select Count(*),byMonth(date_puchased) as x
from myTable
where ...
group by x
having ...
```

this should work for you.

Comment: Aw the query looks horrible for me.. :) So first I need to set up a function? What is the use of the function above?

Comment: the function is for generating a unique column for the sales of a unique month. @Pascalz's answer is as mine with minimum code. choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can retrieve the dates and use PHP as it is pretty straight forward.

Once you have a date lets say for example,

```
$date_str = "2014-01-03 12:00:59"; //let's say you fetch this from DB
$month = date('m',strtotime($date_str)); //this will automatically output 1
```

You mentioned, 2 represents Jan, 3 represents Feb etc, so you can just add 1 to $month and you have what you need.

Comment: It is faster to calculate in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it should work

```
SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM sales_table GROUP BY DATENAME(month, date_purchased)
```

Answer (score 1):

More elaborated solutions

To get Month - wise

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM testrec GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(pur,'%M');
```

Get all details

```
SELECT COUNT(product_id),`name` , date_purchased, DATE_FORMAT(date_purchased,'%M') FROM sales_table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(pur,'%M');
```

Comment: you are retrieving just the month. that is not enough. the first month of this year and the year before are deferent!